# MySQL IF and AND helper

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write an if statement that executes if a user is banned and a time has passed. I have a table named players that has a username, banned, and expires column. How would I check if a player is banned and their ban has expired (expires is before current time) and then call a stored procedure.

This is what I have tried:

```
IF (SELECT p.banned FROM players p WHERE p.username=user = 1 AND p.expires FROM players p WHERE p.username=user < NOW()) THEN
Call unban(user);
END IF;
```

I have found how to do it, here is the code but most people reading this probably already know how to do this.

```
    IF (SELECT p.banned FROM players p WHERE p.username=user)=1 AND (SELECT p.expires FROM players p WHERE p.username=user) < NOW() THEN
    Call unban(user);
    END IF;
```

Comment: IF is a function if you want ot use it as flow control you need it in a BEGIN END block

Answer (score 1):

use it in three steps:

1. [join table](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) users and player
2. check where expires > NOW()
3. execute the function on result query